# Rails nested attribute not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, schema, persistence

In my models I have

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog

  validates :blog, :name, presence: true
end
```

Blog Controller

```
def new
    @blog = Blog.new
    @blog.tags.build
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @blog, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title', class: ('form-control') %>
 </div><br>

  <%= f.fields_for :tags do |builder| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= builder.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Tags' %>
  </div><br>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions text-center">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Blog Controller

```
def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
    binding.pry
 end

 def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :author, :text, :avatar, :banner, :tags_attributes => [:id, :name])
    end
```

At my binding, it says @blog's error message is that it can't be saved because the Tag object is missing a blog_id. I have looked everywhere and I have tried to replicate my code to match other solutions but to no success.

If it helps, in my params when I submit the form I get this

```
"tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"dsfsf"}}
```

Comment: Try changing `f.fields_for :tags` to `f.fields_for :tags_attributes`? @Edmund Lee is otherwise correct, you should be using `create` instead of `new` here to save the object to the db.

Comment: nope that didn't work. I only have the blog.new there because I have blog.save down in my code which I didn't include in my question

Comment: @brandoncodes @Glyoko, it's because he is validating presence of :id in `Tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because your `@blog` is not persisted in the db yet, so you won't have the `id`.

In your `Tag` model, remove `:id` from validation.

You should be able to just do `Blog.create(blog_params)`

Rails should handle the rest for you.

Comment: @brandoncodes sorry for my oversight. see my edit. In your Tag model, remove :id from validation.

Comment: np at all! Yea I was about to post that. That what I just did and it worked. Thanks!